# Why is the setof points where a function f defined on a metric is continuous is the intersection of countable number of open sets?

Tags: real-analysis

Why is the set of points where a function f defined on a metric is continuous is the intersection of countable number of open sets?
Can anyone give me any idea?

Here is what I have come up with.
Let $S(n) = \{ |f(x)-f(y)| < \ 1/n \ and \ \rho(x, y)<\delta_n\}$
If we can prove that S(n) is open. Then $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}s(n)$ is the set of points where f is continous.
But how to prove that S(n) is open?